# Why I can't edit question because of the title?

Tags: bug, edits

I was trying to edit someone else's question today to fix the formatting, but I got "the question with the same title already exists" warning. But I don't wanna edit the title, I only wanna fix the formatting.

The OP is allowed to post the question with that title but it's not allowed in the edit, seems like an inconsistent behaviour. Why it is like that?